# Parsing icaldav events matching a time range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, icloud, caldav

I'm using iclouddav(https://github.com/jcs/iclouddav) module with ri_cal gem('https://github.com/rubyredrick/ri_cal') to parse calendars with Rails from an iCloud account.

Everything works just fine, but the calendar.events requests can take up to 30s. I would say this is because calendar.events fetches all events without any time limit.

I saw the caldav protocol seems to allow this (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4791.txt, section 7.8.1). Does anyone have a clue on what to do to have reasonable response times ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to implement the REPORT request on the iclouddav module. It was possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at this Gem instead ? https://github.com/n8vision/caldav-icloud

It seems more up to date than the gem you're using.

And the ability to find events within time interval may speed up the query a lot.